# How to do subsections for a homework problem?

Tags: sectioning

I have a homework question and I have `\section*{Problem 1}` which has parts `(a), (b)...`
how do I properly section each part?

Comment: An `enumerate` environment?

Comment: This depends on what you want to obtain, and on how long these parts are: single sentences ? several paragraphs ? Please post more detail.

Comment: Well the question involves determining if 6 different mappings are homomorphisms, describing their kernals and then specifying the type or morphism (isomorphism, epimorphism, monomorphism).

Comment: @spitfiredd: Please specify the *typesetting* problems in more detail. Otherwise the question becomes a candidate for closing because of "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem, and shows what you tried.  This also helps to make it clearer what you are asking, as sometimes an alternate solutions can be proposed.

Answer (score 6):

Given the description of the requirement given by the OP in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172837/how-to-do-subsections-for-a-homework-problem#comment399291_172837), I'd suggest a simple `enumerate` environment, in which the labels have been changed with the help of the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to produce the required labeling; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item The mapping $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=x+2$ is not a group homomorphism of additive groups because $f(0)=2\neq 0$.
\item The mapping $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$ given by... 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use

```
\subsection*{a}

part a text


\subsection*{b}

part b text
```

Comment: hard coding enumerations is generally bad practice

Answer (score 1):

```
\section{Home work}
\subsection{Home work 1
\subsubsection{Home work 1.1}
```

This can go on. If you don't need the section number put `*` before bracket in sections.